# Ejecutar una segundo método post (API) después de recibir la respuesta del primer método post

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo el siguiente inconveniente, ya no sé que más hacer, tengo un método post el cual envió un JSON y hasta ahí todo bien, recibo la respuesta que es un ID, el detalle es que para que yo pueda guardar en la segunda API tengo que esperar esa respuesta y agregarlo en mi variable id_institucion. pero más no puedo.

```js
this.apisInstitucionesService.createInstitucion(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonFInal))).subscribe({
            next: (v) =>{
              if(v != null ){
                this.refreshTable();
                this.messageService.add({severity: 'success', summary: 'Completado', detail: 'Institución creado correctamente.', life: 3000});
                const id = v[0];
                this.id_institucion = Number(id.success); 
                console.log(this.id_institucion)    
                
                /* Guardado de la pestaña Asesor (Contacto) */
                if(this.id_institucion != 0){
                  console.log(this.id_institucion);
                  if(this.informacion_Contacto.length){
                    for (let contacto of this.informacion_Contacto) {

                      let idinstitucion = contacto.id_institucion;
                      contacto.id_institucion = idinstitucion == 0 ? this.id_institucion : 0;
                    
                      this.apisAsesoresService.createAsesor(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(contacto))).subscribe({
                        next: (v) =>{
                          if(v != null ){
                            //this.refreshTable();
                            this.messageService.add({severity: 'success', summary: 'Completado', detail: 'Asesor creado correctamente.', life: 3000});
                          }else{
                            this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Error , asesor no se pudo crear.', life: 3000});
                          }
                        },
                        error: (e) =>{
                          this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Error al guardar el asesor.', life: 3000});
                          console.error(e);
                        }, 
                        complete: () => console.info('complete asesor') 
                      });
                    }
                  }
                } else{
                  console.log('no entra api 1')
                  console.log(this.id_institucion);
                }
```

En **this.id_institucion = Number(id.success);** guardó mi id numérica y lo trato de anexar a **contacto.id_institucion** porque tengo una clase en otro archivo .ts donde declaro los atributos tengo un id_institucion: any = 0 y en mi formulario HTML no lo tengo porque previamente se tiene que guardar la institucion y enseguida otro registro que consulta la segunda API y por eso declaro en mi clase id_institucion como cero para luego poder sustituirlo.

No sé si es mucho rollo, pero lo que quiero en resumen es cuando la primera inserción en mi API se realice y esta me devuelva el ID que ya lo hace es asignarlo a contacto.id_institucion y hacer el guardado del método post de la segunda API.

Ya cheque en consola y me trae el, id, pero no puedo hacer la segunda inserción a ala segunda, lo metí porque cuando termina la primera enseguida se ejecuta la segunda API y no espera la respuesta y ya luego de guardado me muestra el id de la primera.

Actualización

Si lo pongo por fuera de la primera método se guarda, pero como aún no se obtiene la respuesta de la primera tengo el id_institucion en cero, por lo que no hace el cambio porque aún no se obtiene la respuesta.

dejo imagen: El undefined es por que aun no pasa la condición del primer if, ya que aún no se recibe la respuesta de la primera inserción. esto teniendo las dos métodos separados si pongo el segundo dentro de la primera no ejecuta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si necesitas esperar respuestas de una API quizas debas hacerlo de forma asincrona, estas familiarizado con las Promesas, Async/Await y la sintaxis que hay detras?

Comment: no amigo no estoy familiarizado con lo uqe mencionas, lei un poco de eso pero nunca los he usado,

Comment: siempre podes consultar la pagina de Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing . Es un tema bastante avanzado pero muy util ahi tenes recomendaciones problemas comunes requisitos antes de adentrarte en el tema.

Comment: la documentacion es de Javascript pero sirve igual solo cambia la sintaxis un poco por el tema de los tipos pero todo lo que funciona en JS puede implementarse en TS

Comment: Entonces por lo como estoy haciendo actualmente no se va a poder? es pregunta amigo

Comment: Si necesitas hacer peticiones y recibir respuestas que despues te sirvan para hacer otra cosa necesitas si o si usar TypeScript asincrono, no hay otra forma de decirle al codigo que debe esperar un tiempo X para recibir una respuesta, te recomendaria empezar con las Promesas, que son un objeto en Typescript pero tambien podes crearlas tu mismo.

Comment: Hola amigo @ElFuturoLlego si es lo que ando viendo de lo primero que mencionaste, el problema es que me estan pidiendo este requisito para ya, prácticamente tengo hasta las 7 nde la noche para entregar este código resuelto, no es que me hagan el trabajo, pero si pudieras mostrarme un ejemplo en el código que tengo de como seria para que yo lo implemente te lo super agradecería muchisimo. por que ya la verdad llevo desde la mañana y no doy ni una mas, hasya ahora recibo la respuesta que es un id pero no logro hacer  lo demas :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140238/discussion-between-elfuturo-llego-and-oscarggh).